# Query with multiple should

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a use case which in need to build a query that contains this kind of logic:

`(condition1 OR condition2 OR condition3) AND (condition4 OR condition5) AND condition6`

How can I implement it with elastic search?

If I use `bool` query with `should` and `filter` I must define `minimum_should_match: 1` but it doesn't solve how I can execute multi  OR/should queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would look like

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "bool": {
          "should": [condition1, condition2, condition3],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "bool": {
          "should": [condition4, condition5],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      },
      condition6
    ]
  }
}
```

Where condition may look like

```
{
  "term": {
    "field": "value"
  }
}
```